# Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync isn't working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

### Question:

I haven't found much about [MSTest V2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/) for examples or [documentation](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/MSTest.TestFramework/). What is the correct way to use Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync?

```
public void GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException()
{
    var playlistId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var manager = PlaylistTargetsFakeFactory.GetPlaylistTargetFusionManager();
    Assert.ThrowsException<PlaylistNotFoundException>(async () =>
    {
       await manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId);
    });
}
```

this also fails the test:

```
Assert.ThrowsException<PlaylistNotFoundException>(() =>
{
    return manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId);
});
```

> Message: Assert.ThrowsException failed. No exception thrown.
> PlaylistNotFoundException exception was expected.

This is failing for me, even though I've debugged it and the exception is definitely thrown.

Since this is still an RC, it's possible there is a bug. I've had this in 2 tests I'm trying to convert so I can use VS 2017.

### *Update:* This passes.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException()
{
    var playlistId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var manager = PlaylistTargetsFakeFactory.GetPlaylistTargetFusionManager();
    //Assert.ThrowsException<PlaylistNotFoundException>(() =>
    //{

    try
    {
        await manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId);
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (PlaylistNotFoundException)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    //});
}
```

**Update 2:** After Stephen Cleary's answer, I made this change. Thanks for pointing out my mis-use. I had changed it awhile back because I get "Message: Test method .Test.Models.Helpers.PlaylistTargetFusionManagerTests.GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException threw exception:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync(System.Func`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)'." when I run the test.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.CSharp)]
[TestCategory(TestCategories.PlaylistTargets)]
public async Task GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException()
{
    var playlistId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var manager = PlaylistTargetsFakeFactory.GetPlaylistTargetFusionManager();
    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<PlaylistNotFoundException>(() => manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId));
}
```

I have 2 packages in my packages.json

```
 <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.9-rc2" targetFramework="net451" />
 <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.0.8-rc2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> What is the correct way to use Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync?

You're not calling [`ThrowsExceptionAsync`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/MSTest.TestFramework/1.0.8-rc2/net45/doc/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert/ThrowsExceptionAsync''1(System.Func(System.Threading.Tasks.Task))). You're calling [`ThrowsException`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/MSTest.TestFramework/1.0.8-rc2/net45/doc/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert/ThrowsException''1(System.Action)). The proper way to call `ThrowsExceptionAsync` is to `await` its result.

This should work:

```
public async Task GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException()
{
  var playlistId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  var manager = PlaylistTargetsFakeFactory.GetPlaylistTargetFusionManager();
  await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<PlaylistNotFoundException>(async () =>
  {
     await manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId);
  });
}
```

or, more simply:

```
  await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<PlaylistNotFoundException>(() =>
     manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made an edit showing the problem I have with the ThrowsExceptionAsync

Comment: It works if I use .Net 4.5.2. I'm going to report a bug

Answer (score 2):

Because your method is async you can try something like this, that also allows you to test the values of the raised exception:

```
public void GetPlaylistByIdAsync_NonExistingPlaylist_ThrowsPlaylistNotFoundException()
{
    var playlistId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var manager = PlaylistTargetsFakeFactory.GetPlaylistTargetFusionManager();

    var ex = Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<PlaylistNotFoundException>(
            async () =>
            {
                await manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId);
            }).Result;

    Assert.IsTrue(ex.ErrorCode == ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all that I went through in my question, I created a simple new project, which was .Net 4.5.2 and that worked. After I realized the .Net version difference, I changed my project and the test passed. I realize that we need to upgrade, since 4.5.1 is [no longer supported by Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx) and will start working on that as soon as I can. I guess this would have made a better blog post than an SO question.

The **main fix** is to change the packages.json to change targetFramework="net451" to targetFramework="net452".

```
<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.9-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.0.8-rc2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making your tests async and using await use this: `Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<PlaylistNotFoundException>(() => manager.GetPlaylistByIdAsync(playlistId)).Wait();`
The wait is helpful for testing async methods